# gst-launch-1.0: undefined symbol: _gst_date_time_type

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

gst-inspect-1.0 shows error for the following command:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="url/path"
```

*Error: gst-launch-1.0: symbol lookup error: gst-launch-1.0: undefined symbol: _gst_date_time_type*

I tried few suggested links with no success: [Gstreamer gst-launch-1.0: symbol lookup error: gst-launch-1.0: undefined symbol: _gst_date_time_type](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518628/gstreamer-gst-launch-1-0-symbol-lookup-error-gst-launch-1-0-undefined-symbol)

Comment: Is this because of two versions of gstreamers installed on my system? i.e gstreamer-1.4.0 and 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this problem by using command: sudo ldconfig